# How to $scope use a firebase object on an Angular App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I am new to coding, and a basic answer would be very much appreciated.

I am trying to use firebase object as a javascript array to use it on html using $scope. what would be the best method?

database:
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3uN1.png)

I am using:

```js
var mainApp = angular.module("bookWorm", []);

mainApp.controller('bookController', function($scope, $http) {

  var ref = firebase.database().ref("Fiction");

  ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {

    console.log(snapshot.val());
    $scope.fiction = snapshot.val();

  });


});
```

```html
<div class="contents">
  <div class="heading">
    <h2 style="text-align:center">Fiction</h2>
  </div>
  <u1 style="cursor:pointer">
    <li ng-repeat="content in fiction"><img src="assets/fiction/{{content.book}}.png" width="200px" height="200px"></li>
  </u1>
</div>
```

for which I am getting the following in the console:

```
Object {-Km712C_iBij3OkXCR1s: Object, -Km71G_rHgirXWZi1xh6: Object, -Km71Rje4ZeluNYtK8x_: Object, -Km71gTdrfgC1BeXIPPU: Object, -Km71x6C-s_FFTcEMYCc: Object…}
```

-Km71G_rHgirXWZi1xh6
:
Object
author
:
"Ashwin Sanghi"
book
:
"chanakya'sChant"
cost
:
"300"
**proto**
:
Object
-Km71Rje4ZeluNYtK8x_
:
Object
-Km71gTdrfgC1BeXIPPU
:
Object
-Km71x6C-s_FFTcEMYCc
:
Object
-Km72Bg8o63vuNBqnU4D
:
Object
-Km72VI64weNgpMJTXCL
:
Object
-Km72d4OIl3pz5BylWc4
:
Object
-Km72kkzjTksropLmXzY
:
Object
-Km72tZ4u2CIPpK8FU_n
:
Object
-Km73NBgknkSUHytQmY5
:
Object
-Km74QCIFrgrOhzp7IIP
:
Object
-Km712C_iBij3OkXCR1s
:
Object
-Km739xvEa1StJHvWcka
:
Object
**proto**
:
Object

**but I am not able to list the "book" elements.** please help with some examples.

Comment: where is the `bookController` in the html?

Comment: moreover; for dynamic src in angular; use ng-src https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Comment: thanks @AgamBanga .

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just use the angular firebase module so it will handle triggering the apply/digest on the rootScope when changes occur to get the view to update:

https://github.com/firebase/angularfire

You could also add $scope.$apply to your code but without understanding this it is ill advised.

Answer (score 0):

What about to try (key, value) pair in ng-repeat as i worked with firebase a lot of ionic apps. This is the most efficient way to show data. Here example for your question

```js
var mainApp = angular.module("bookWorm", []);

mainApp.controller('bookController', function($scope, $http) {

  var ref = firebase.database().ref("Fiction");

  ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {

    console.log(snapshot.val());
    $scope.fiction = snapshot.val();

  });


});
```

```html
<div class="contents">
  <div class="heading">
    <h2 style="text-align:center">Fiction</h2>
  </div>
  <ul style="cursor:pointer">
    <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in fiction"><img src="assets/fiction/{{value.book}}.png" width="200px" height="200px"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```